# Using filter strtolower in custom Twig Extension return no result

Tags: theming, 8

I created a module to extend Twig Extension for filter functions. However the usage of strtolower in custom module end up with no result. Below are the sampel code of my custom module.

```
  public static function removeSpaces($string) {
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);

    return $string;
  }
```

Filtering `{{ title|removeSpaces }}` in template end up with empty.

Comment: Can you debug what goes into the function and what comes out. Are those really strings?

Comment: Debug shows the strings {{ title }} is an array:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to render the array and then use the custom twig filter:

```
{{ title|render|removeSpaces }}
```